# Example requests for REST API for OpenRemote

Tags: rest

I am trying to use the OpenRemote HTTP API to search for an asset using its name.  It's simple when you know its ID because you just use a GET request with the path `/asset/THE_ASSET_ID`, but when querying by name, I believe I have to POST to `/asset/query`.  However, [the Swagger](https://demo.openremote.io/swagger/#/Asset/queryAssets) shows a huge JSON structure to send, the majority of which I doubt is required.

I went fairly minimal and sent:

```json
{
  "types": [ "ThingAsset" ],
  "names": [
    {
      "value": "the name to find"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I get an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error back, and the log indicates that I'm missing a `predicateType` parameter; but there isn't one in the area of the JSON that I'm using.

The section of JSON for `names` is:

```json
  "names": [
    {
      "match": "string",
      "caseSensitive": true,
      "value": "string",
      "negate": true
    }
  ],
```

I haven't been able to find a description of what each element of the JSON is, so for example, where it says `"string"`, it's not clear (to me) what the string should be.  And I assume I wouldn't need to supply both `match` and `value`.  I'm working on the assumption that `match` is a regular expression and `value` is a static string.  But perhaps `match` is supposed to be `static` or `regexp` and `value` is the corresponding value.  The point is, I can't find any definition of what's what!

[The implementation](https://github.com/openremote/openremote/blob/83a4d9ddde8f52220c1929846e3bbd0b2bf7865d/manager/src/main/java/org/openremote/manager/asset/AssetResourceImpl.java#L573) for `queryAssets` in the source code (which I *think* is where the `/asset/query` request ends up) doesn't refer to the `RequestParams` object, so I have to assume that the JSON's content ends up in the `AssetQuery` object.  But that's another rabbit hole to go down.

Does anyone have any experience with the OpenRemote RESTful API?  Is there any documentation that says what's actually required in a request to `/asset/query`, particularly when wanting to search by name?

(By the way, I don't have sufficient reputation to add an `OpenRemote` tag.)

Answer (score 1):

I also [asked this question over on the OpenRemote forum](https://forum.openremote.io/t/how-do-i-find-an-asset-by-name-using-the-http-api/1656) (which I found after posting here).

[Rich](https://forum.openremote.io/u/Rich) kindly [responded with the solution](https://forum.openremote.io/t/how-do-i-find-an-asset-by-name-using-the-http-api/1656/3), which, for the example I gave above, is:

```json
{
  "types": [ "ThingAsset" ],
  "names": [
    {
      "match": "EXACT",
      "value": "the name to find",
      "predicateType": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

(As a slight aside, my tests show I didn't even need to include the `"types"` attribute.)